# Angular : ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, angular, http, observable

Hi I need help I created an angular service but when I want to view the data from my json file it shows me this error, I tried a lot of unsuccessful solution

app.component.ts

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import {Car} from './domain/car';
    import {CarService} from './service/carservice';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      providers: [CarService]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      cars1: Car[];
      constructor(private carService: CarService) { }

      ngOnInit() {
       this.carService.getCarsSmall().subscribe(cars => this.cars1 = cars);
      }
    }
```

carservice.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class CarService {

  private jsonUrl = './cars-smalll.json';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
    getCarsSmall(): Observable<Car[]> {
      return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
      let body = res.json();
      return body.data || { };
    }
    private handleError (error: Response | any) {
      // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
      let errMsg: string;
      if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
      } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
      }
      console.error(errMsg);
      return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

cars-smalll.json

```
[
    {
      "brand": "VW",
      "year": 2012,
      "color": "Orange",
      "vin": "dsad231ff"
    },
    {
      "brand": "Audi",
      "year": 2011,
      "color": "Black",
      "vin": "gwregre345"
    },
    {
      "brand": "Renault",
      "year": 2005,
      "color": "Gray",
      "vin": "h354htr"
    }
]
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: This error is *almost always* caused by a server configuration issue, and not by angular at all.  The server is sending an HTML document instead of one of your javascript files.  What server are you using here, and what does your server's routing configuration look like?

Comment: or mock JSON path is incorrect, what you see in browser's Network log?

Comment: Thanks Claies for your reply, so in my case I want to use a json file that store in the same structure (src / app / data / cars-smalll.json)

Comment: Add Json file under assets and then run

Comment: i try to put json in assets folder, and i change path of json to (/src/app/assets/cars-smalll.json) but i get the same error

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure how much more help I can be. Try posting on [Angular 2+](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/) at reddit. There are some really helpful people over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Besides using the correct path suggested in comments, your problem is that you are trying to extract data from something that does not exist. Take a look at your json, it's an array. But in your `extractData`-function you are trying to extract data from an object `data`, which is of course not present in your JSON. So change that function to:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  // return just the response, or an empty array if there's no data
  return body || []; 
}
```

This should do it, as well as correcting the path of the JSON file.

Comment: Thank you very much, you help me I did not pay attention to it, a remark is that in my case the  json path is the following (../../assets/data/cars-small.json), that work for me,